# Отслеживание изменений

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Есть таблица, в которой описана структура каталога сайта.
Периодически, то ли скриптом, то ли руками, переписываются некоторые значения.

У кого-нить есть идеи, как можно в MySQL отследить вносимые изменения и выяснить кто их делает(юзер или скрипт и какой скрипт)?

- С триггерами ничего не вышло.
- Бинлоги админ отключил.

**UPD:** По факту мне нужно отследить кто хулиганит, остальное вторично.
**UPD 2:** Как выяснилось у phpmyadmin касяк с триггерами. Поставил триггер из IDE заработал. Но проблема с хулиганом всё равно остаётся.
**UPD 3:** Наверное не стоит зацикливаться на логах мускла. Как можно **вообще** отловить скрипт меняющей запись?

Comment: А что именно не получилось с триггерами? Через триггер можно отследить что меняется и когда.

Comment: в сторону delayed job, и не надо дампы сравнивать, это убийство. или вам нужно просто узнать что за бяка данные меняет?

а по сути согласен с KiTE

Comment: именно бяку надо найти

Comment: в таком случае, в mysql можно отслеживать последние запросы из них отлавливать нужные, но по вашему вопросу картина довольно мутная, нужно больше информации

Comment: @pavelbel какая именно?

Comment: для начала какие у вас права на серваке?

Comment: разумеется root :)

Comment: если root, тогда почему "Бинлоги админ отключил" )) ну ладно, может все таки "в mysql можно отслеживать последние запросы из них отлавливать нужные"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем всё оказалось проще:
 1. Тригеры не вешались из-за какого-то косяка в пхпмайадмине. Из консоли отлично заработали
 2. Когда стало видно как именно поступают изменения, начал ковырять код.
 3. Выяснилось, что если привязать какой-либо новый элемент к каталогу сайта, каталог повторно строится системой с дефолтными настройками.
 4. Влепил заплатку и сплю спокойно.

Comment: как бы теперь на себя галочку поставить и закрыть вопрос :(

Answer (score 1):

вы уверены, что не путаете права доступа к ОС и права доступа к БД?

Comment: root могу и в ОС и в БД, но на ОС предпочитаю не лазить, так как факин фряха. Пускай админ сам с ней лобызание.

Comment: да уж не очень то она и факин)) короче если есть рут к ОС, тогда все проще, пишется скрипт, который читает логи на апдейт (слушатель) и пишет результат куданить

Comment: В данном случае речь идёт о всё ещё о логах мускла? Или о логах самой системы?

Comment: и о том и о другом, слушаем порт бд-шки
upd: хреново выразился
для нормальной работы с логами, нужны права, и для записи результата тоже нужны права :)

Comment: Предвкушаю вспомнить перл :)

Answer (score -1):

ежедневный дампы таблицы и сравнение между собой дампов) А вот кем они сделаны, уже не знаю  как определить